# margin end/right is not working on item in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, margins

First see the layout for my point

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY3HC.png)

Here is XML

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainCL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bankInfoHeadingTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
            android:text="Bank Information"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bankInfoIconIV"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bankInfoHeadingTV"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/bankInfoHeadingTV"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bankInfoHeadingTV" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to put some space between **bankInfoHeadingTV** and **bankInfoIconIV**.
So it put the margin of 30dp at the end of **bankInfoHeadingTV** but it is not working.
Margin start with **bankInfoIconIV** is working but why margin end with **bankInfoHeadingTV** is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only set margins for a view if you have the constraint. Because you constrained your ImageViews start to the end of textView you can set the start margin for the image. If you reversed it and constrained the end of yout TextView to the ImageView you can set the margin in the TextView.